# Multiple random values in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, random

I need to generate multiple random values under SQL Server 2005 and somehow this simply won't work

```
with Random(Value) as
(
    select rand() Value
        union all
    select rand() from Random
    
)select top 10 * from Random
```

What's the preferred workaround?

Comment: I like questions like this that force me to go to learn something new! Thanks! Hope the answer helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tries something like this (found at [http://weblogs.sqlteam.com](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2004/11/22/2927.aspx) ) :

```
CREATE VIEW vRandNumber
AS
SELECT RAND() as RandNumber
GO
```

create a function

```
CREATE FUNCTION RandNumber()
RETURNS float
AS
  BEGIN
     RETURN (SELECT RandNumber FROM vRandNumber)
  END
GO
```

then you can call it in your selects as normal
Select dbo.RandNumber() , * from myTable

or from their comments:

```
select RAND(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(6))), * from myTable
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems like the solution from their comments is about the samething that I came up with after some tinkering. Really odd that it doesnt get revaluated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using this:

```
with Random(Value) as
(
    select rand(checksum(newid())) Value
        union all
    select rand(checksum(newid())) from Random  
)select top 10 * from Random
```

but that seems overly hackish :S
Why doesnt rand get reevaluated in the first version?

Comment: That will have as much entropy as newid(). checksum() and rand() are both deterministic in this context.