# Turn off implicit transactions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I would like to do a insert into using a select, but I know that some rows might fail (that is expected). Is there a way to change the implicit transactions of SQL Server 2008 off so that the ones that have not failed are not rolled back?

```
-- get the count of the customers to send the sms to
SELECT @count = COUNT(*)
FROM PreCampaignCustomer
WHERE Processed = 0 AND CampaignID = @campaignid 
AND ErrorCount < 5

WHILE (@count > 0)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @customerid INT,
            @carrierid INT,
            @merchantcustomerid INT,
            @smsnumber NVARCHAR(50),
            @couponcode NVARCHAR(20)

    SELECT TOP 1 @customerid = pcc.CustomerID, @merchantcustomerid = pcc.MerchantCustomerID,
    @carrierid = c.CarrierID, @smsnumber = c.SMSNumber 
    FROM PreCampaignCustomer pcc
    INNER JOIN Customer c ON c.ID = pcc.CustomerID
    WHERE pcc.Processed = 0 AND pcc.CampaignID = @campaignid
    AND pcc.ErrorCount < 5
    ORDER BY pcc.ErrorCount

    --set the couponcode    
    IF @couponlength = -1 
    BEGIN
        SET @couponcode = 'NOCOUPON'
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        EXEC [GenerateCouponCode]
        @length = 9,
        @couponcode = @couponcode OUTPUT
    END

    BEGIN TRY
        --use try/catch just in case the coupon code is repeated or any other error

        --Set the coupon text
        DECLARE @coupontext NVARCHAR(200),
                @smsrequestxml XML


        IF @coupontypecode = 1 --NONE
        BEGIN 
            SET @coupontext = @merchantname + ': ' + @smsmessage + ', Use Code: ' + dbo.FormatCouponCode(@couponcode, @couponcodegrouping) + '. Reply STOP to quit'
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @coupontext = @merchantname + ': ' + @smsmessage + '. Reply STOP to quit'
        END

        EXEC GetSMSRequest @config = @smsconfig, 
                    @smsType = 1, --Submit
                    @address = @smsnumber,
                    @carrierID = @carrierid,
                    @message = @coupontext,
                    @xml = @smsrequestxml OUTPUT

        BEGIN TRAN
            --create the CampaignCustomer record
            INSERT INTO CampaignCustomer
            (CampaignID, CustomerID, CouponCode, Active)
            VALUES
            (@campaignid, @customerid, @couponcode, 1)

            --Add the record to the queue
            INSERT INTO SMSQueue
            (CarrierID, [Address], [Message], TimeToSend, RequestXML, QueueID, HTTPStatusCode, Retries)
            VALUES
            (@carrierid, @smsnumber, @coupontext, @timetosend, @smsrequestxml, @queueid, 0, 0)

            --Create Outgoing SMS Log
            INSERT INTO SMSOutgoingLog
            (MerchantID, MerchantGroupID, MessageTypeCode, CreatedDate, Active)
            VALUES 
            (@merchantid, @merchantgroupid, @messagetypecode, GETDATE(), 1)

            --Update the LastSentSMSTime of the MerchantCustomer
            UPDATE MerchantCustomer
            SET LastSentSMS = GETDATE(),
            ModifiedDate = GETDATE()
            WHERE ID = @merchantcustomerid

            UPDATE PreCampaignCustomer
            SET Processed = 1,
            ModifiedDate = GETDATE()
            WHERE CustomerID = @customerid 
            AND CampaignID = @campaignid
        COMMIT TRAN
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRAN

        -- Set the error
        UPDATE PreCampaignCustomer
        SET ErrorCount = ErrorCount + 1,
        ModifiedDate = GETDATE(),
        ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
        ErrorNumber = ERROR_NUMBER()
        WHERE CustomerID = @customerid 
        AND CampaignID = @campaignid
    END CATCH

    SELECT @count = COUNT(*)
    FROM PreCampaignCustomer
    WHERE Processed = 0 AND CampaignID = @campaignid 
    AND ErrorCount < 5
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, the INSERT is a single command.  Transactions control how multiple commands are combined together into single units of work, and not how rows are combined within a single command.   You can't have some rows INSERT and the ones that fail (some constraint issue) and just be ignored.  if any rows fail, then the entire INSERT fails.

why not try modifying the SELECT to exclude rows that will fail?

something like:

```
INSERT INTO YourTable
        (col1, col2, col3)
    SELECT
        colA, colB, ColC
        FROM YourOtherTable
        WHERE ColA NOT IN (SELECT col1 FROM YourTable)
```

Comment: I generate a random coupon code for each row and there is a unique constraint on the coupon code. Instead of doing a select to see if it exists I let SQL Server handle the constraint and let it fail. Do you think checking for count(*) with that coupon code will be faster?

Comment: are you looping, with one insert per iteration? if so post the code so I can see exactly what is going on.  there are ways to generate a set of random numbers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183124/multiple-random-values-in-sql-server-2005/183183#183183.  Also COUNT(*) is slow (it does more work) than just a plain EXISTS.

Comment: yes, i am looping. I added the code. Bottom line I need to make this query as a efficient as possible. Maybe instead of getting the count on every iteration just execute the select top 1 and do WHILE NOT @customerid is null. Any other suggestions?

Comment: what problem happens with this code?  I don't see an INSERT+SELECT? that your original question asked about.  it looks like you keep trying until your insert works.

Comment: I'm trying to make this as efficient as possible. insert select would make it so, but there is no way to do so if one fails and that's why I went with this approach.

Comment: any suggestions to make it more efficient?

Comment: the only way to remove the loop would to rewrite `EXEC [GenerateCouponCode] ...` and `EXEC GetSMSRequest` to work set wise. link in my first comment shows how to produce a set of random nums and you can use table input parameters since you are on SQL Server 2008. Possibly you could create a new table that you pre-populate (nightly job) with many unique random values, then in this procedure you just get the next one from this table.  Another way would be to use the link from my first comment to generate a huge set of random values and then use the top N that you need to insert the unique ones.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking out of the box, if you use SSIS to do this, you can send your failed rows down a differnt path or just throw them out.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably thinking about the IGNORE_DUP_KEY property of a unique index.

See [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594193/can-i-set-ignore-dup-key-on-for-a-primary-key) and [the official MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175132.aspx) on IGNORE_DUP_KEY.

You'll have to either use ALTER INDEX to add this property, or (if the unique constraint is on the primary key) drop and re-create it.

Once this is in place, any inserts should only reject invalid rows instead of the entire batch.

Comment: is there a way to get the rows that failed after the insert?

Comment: we decided not to go with this solution because it affects the performance of non clustered indexes. We did utilize it to allocate pre defined coupon codes. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to control behaviour of transansactions using SET XACT_ABORT OFF (ON) -- **[more here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188792.aspx)**.